# Error in SQL statement for Derby database

Tags: java, sql, derby

I'm havin an error while trying to execute this piece of sql code... The error I'm getting is:

```
Encountered "(" at line 1, column 45
```

The piece of code is:

```
ALTER TABLE APP.RESPOSTAS ADD coluna" + (numColumns + 1) + " INTEGER(1) AFTER coluna" + numColumns;
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you all!

Comment: What do you expect the eventual SQL to look like? Have you run it by hand in ij?

Answer (score 1):

According to [The derby details for INTEGER](http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/reference/sqlj136.html#HDRSII-SQLJ-10696) you don't need the (1) in there.

```
ALTER TABLE APP.RESPOSTAS ADD coluna" + (numColumns + 1) + " INTEGER
```

should work?

edited to remove the `AFTER` section as it doesn't look like derby supports that either.
[here are the derby details for ALTER TABLE](http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/reference/sqlj26.html#HDRSII-SQLJ-33145)

Comment: Not workin Yet... Now I have the following error:
"Encountered "AFTER" at line 1, column 46"

Comment: You don't get to control the column order, either, so remove "after coluna+numColumns" from the statement, too. Your statement should just be: alter table app.respostas add columnaN